# Angular material stepper bullet icon change color based on condition

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview to build a vertical stepper, but how can make each icon color is different based on condition.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttscbh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-vertical-example.css)

Example is like this

[image]

Comment: Has my answer helped you? @B.Cos

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution:

In your css:

```
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon{
    background-color: red !important;
}

.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-done,
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-edit {
    background-color: green !important;
}

.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

And remember to declare `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your @Component declaration like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-vertical-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-vertical-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-vertical-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

You have a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttscbh-jj9vul?file=src/app/stepper-vertical-example.ts)

Comment: Hi, this seem like set all icon to red when initialize, can each mat-step can set different color based on a flag (example variable isRed= true) ? Because I have long list of mat-step and each icon need to either blue or red based on some flag condition